# VSCode setting "debug.inlineValues:on" is not working for inline debug in PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I am debugging PHP successfully with Xdebug in VSCode. But I want to inspect the variables inline, like in PhpStorm:

[image: PhpStorm Inline debugging]

I've configured VSCode with the following:

```json
"debug.inlineValues": "on",
```

but it is still not working. The setting has no visible effect.

Comment: Looks like its doing it to me, look at the function prototype line where `$driverpool` is expanded

Comment: And the line in highlight has expanded `$directoryList` has it not?

Comment: If it matters, my setting is set to Auto rather than On

Comment: @RiggsFolly that screenshot is like appears in phpstorm. I mean in vsCode is not working like in phpstorm. I don't know why in vsCode doesn't work

Comment: @RiggsFolly is it working to you viewing debug inline for php?

Comment: vscode-php-debug does not yet support this. see https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/671

Comment: This functionality is provided by PHP extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

The official Xdebug VSCode extension [PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) does not yet have support for showing Inline Values while debugging. Here is the issue for tracking: https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/671

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) provides Xdebug and Inline Debug Values.